# setState on only one variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, setstate

I have a react native app with the state:

```
this.state={
        nameOne:"team 1",
        nameTwo:"team 2",
        pointsForEvents:{
            lap: 1,
            homeRun: 5,
            lyre: 3,
            oneHandCatch: 5,
            burned: 1,
            burnOut: 10,
        }
    }
```

Then I want to update the variables in pointsForEvents:

```
<TextInput
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        onChangeText={(lyre) =>{lyre = parseInt(lyre); this.setState({pointsForEvents:{lyre}})}}
        value={this.state.pointsForEvents.lyre+""}
    />
```

But the setState updates the other variables within "pointsForEvents" as well and since a value is not specified, they are set to undefined. How do I update only this one value.

PS: what is the correct vocabulary for a variable within an object (like components are parents to their child components).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100901/best-way-to-update-change-state-object-in-react-native

Comment: You will have to use `Object.assign()` to set the `pointsForEvents`  object to itself + any changes. also can use the `spread operator` e.g `pointsForEvents : {...this.state.pointsForEvents, lyre: 4}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are actually setting `pointsForEvents` to a new value, which is an object containing only a single key `lyre`, therefore the other previously specified keys are not available anylonger and resolve to `undefined`. If you want to keep the other keys in the object and only update the key `lyre`, then you have to copy the old object, update only the one key and use this object to set state of `pointsForEvents`.

Copying of objects can be achieved with the spread operator as shown in the answers.
So the following code creates a new object containing all the keys of `pointsForEvents` plus the updated key lyre with its given value and this is the object you want to set in state. In this case `lyre` is inserted into the object, but since it was already there, it will only get updated.

```
{...this.state.pointsForEvents, lyre}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `spread` operator, like so:

```
onChangeText = {
  (lyre) => {
    lyre = parseInt(lyre);
    this.setState({
      pointsForEvents: {
        ...this.state.pointsForEvents,
        lyre,
      }
    })
  }
}
```

In fact, this option would be better:

```
onChangeText = {
  (lyre) => {
    lyre = parseInt(lyre);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      pointsForEvents: {
        ...state.pointsForEvents,
        lyre,
      }
    }))
  }
}
```

The reason why the second option is better is because `this.setState` doesn't update the state right away, so you may see some anomalies.